# Возможно ли использовать возвращемое функцией значение в генераторе списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно ли использовать возвращаемое функцией значение на следующей итерации генератора списка?

Например, нечто подобное (понимаю, что пример нерабочй):

```py
result = [accum = func(accum, i)  for i in mas]
```

Comment: вот зачем брэйнфакать такими конструкциями? замути нормальный генератор с yield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Python 3.8 добавили [`"Assignment Expressions"`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html). Более подробно в [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

Пример:

```
items = list(range(1, 10))
[ii-1 for x in items if (ii:=x+1) % 3 == 0]
#  NOTE: -------------> ^^^^^^^^^
```

вывод:

```
>>> [2, 5, 8]
```

---

**UPDATE:** этот ответ показывает как использовать возвращенное значение **на одной итерации** генератора. Я не уверен, что `"Assignment Expressions"` видны на следующей итерации генератора.

Comment: Кажется, это никак не решает задачу автора вопроса

Comment: @Xander, это отвечает на часть вопроса -  как использовать возвращаемое значение, но не отвечает на то как использовать это значение на следующей итерации генератора

Answer (score 2):

Для такой задачи лучше использовать не генератор (он не предназначен для работы с изменяемым состоянием), а свертку с накоплением промежуточных значений.

```py
import itertools

def func(x, y):
    return x * y

mas = [2, 3, 4, 5]

result_list = list(itertools.accumulate(mas, func)) # [2, 6, 24, 120]
```

или простую свертку

```py
import functools

result_int = functools.reduce(func, mas) # 120
```

В обоих случях (для `accumulate` - начиная с python 3.8) можно указать начальное значение аккумулятора

```py
result_list = list(itertools.accumulate(mas, func, initial=10)) # [10, 20, 60, 240, 1200]
result_int = functools.reduce(func, mas, 10) # 1200
```